# Retirando virgula da coluna pl sql

Tags: regex, oracle, pl-sql, oracle12c, apex

Boa tarde, tenho uma tabela que tem nomes.
Em algumas linhas o nome está separado por virgula. Ex: Alberto, Luiz

Quero alterar essas linhas para ficar Luiz Alberto

```
DECLARE
  final VARCHAR(50);
  inicio VARCHAR(50);
  string_pronta VARCHAR(110);
BEGIN
  SELECT substr(NOME, instr(NOME, ',') + 1) into final FROM participantes;
  SELECT substr(NOME, 1, instr(NOME, ',') - 1) into inicio FROM participantes;
  string_pronta := inicio || ' ' || final;
  UPDATE participantes
   SET NOME := string_pronta;
END;
```

Comment: Axelmar, você quer apenas remover a vírgula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dessa forma abaixo você conseguirá ter o resultado esperado.
Possivelmente existe uma outra forma até mais elegante de ser feita, mas esta funciona.. :)

> Tabela participantes: 
>   Constante, Filipe | de Tal, Fulano

```
UPDATE participantes SET nome = LTRIM(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(nome, ',[^,]+'), ',') || ' ' || REGEXP_SUBSTR(nome, '[^,]+'));
```

> Tabela participantes (RESULTADO): 
>   Filipe Constante | Fulano de Tal

Caso seja outra necessidade, explique melhor na pergunta que eu ajusto a resposta.

Espero ter ajudado.

> A referência para esta resposta, obtive em:
>   https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php

Comment: Desculpa, digitei errado. Alem de remover a virgula preciso inverter o nome de Constante, Felipe o resultado seria: Felipe Constante

Comment: Ajustei o update que irá resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Dê o feedback se deu certo para você.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado